# Print entire 802.11 WiFi Ethernet frame header with tcpdump (or anything else)

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, tcpdump, mac-address

I'm currently learning about WiFi Ethernet frames and want to sniff raw ethernet traffic from my laptop's WiFi adapter. Running

```
sudo tcpdump -vvv -n -i wifi0 -e
```

prints something like the following:

```
03:16:34.665931 66:55:44:33:22:11 > 11:22:33:44:55:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 178: (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 3400, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 164)
    200.200.200.200.443 > 192.168.0.100.55555: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 136
03:16:34.666127 11:22:33:44:55:66 > 66:55:44:33:22:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 147: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40063, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 133)
    192.168.0.100.55555 > 200.200.200.200.443: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 105
```

where `66:55:44:33:22:11` is AP MAC address, `11:22:33:44:55:66` is local WiFi NIC MAC address.

[Wikipedia 802.11 FrameTypes article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11_Frame_Types) defines 4 MAC addresses in the header, while just 2 are printed by `tcpdump`.

How is it possible to inspect the entire 802.11 Ethernet Frame?

Comment: The general answer to full packet decoding is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (for a GUI) or the terminal version, [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html). I don't know if this will resolve your question, but it's probably worth checking out if you haven't already.

Comment: @larsks `tcpdump` is effectively just about the same as `tshark`, which in turn is the command line variation of `wireshark`.

Comment: @roaima (a) I already said the tshark is the command line version of wireshark (that is what "the terminal version" means) and (b) tshark is capable of complete, verbose packet decoding use the verbose option. It is very different from tcpdump.